# Pushing to a fork

Tags: git

I have forked a public repo(R). And then cloned this fork(F) to my local machine(L).

So to start with, L and F are in sync. Then I made a commit in L and tried to push it to F.But R has meanwhile gone ahead, so git didn't allow me to do so. So I pulled changes from R, and merged them. But now trying to push to F gives me error:

> Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
>   its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
>   'git pull ...') before pushing again.

I am not sure what can I do here. I can see in graph that tip of my current branch is head of origin/master.How can then it be behind its remote counterpart?

[image]

Comment: Has anyone else pushed to the fork `F`?

Comment: No.Its only for me.

Comment: Do a `git fetch` from the relevant remote branch, then `git log --graph --full-history --all --color --oneline`.

Comment: But my local branch already has everything F has, so what would git fetch achieve?

Comment: Can you post a graph?

Comment: Posted an image.

Comment: What does `git status` say? Is the remote `upstream` or `origin`?

Comment: git status:

On branch master

Your branch and 'origin/master' have diverged,
and have 21 and 1 different commits each, respectively.
  (use "git pull" to merge the remote branch into yours)

nothing to commit, working tree clean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you would work on a fork is by creating a dedicated branch:

```
git clone yourFork L
cd L
git checkout -b myBranch
# work and commit

git push -u origin myBranch
```

(no problem with "branch behind counterpart" here)

Then, you might want to make sure the original repo has not evolved in the meantime:

```
git remote add upstream /url/original/repo
git fetch upstream
git checkout myBranch
git rebase upstream/master
git push --force
```

Comment: @Mandroid But with the workflow I describe, you won't have issues when pushing.

Comment: Now I got what you are trying to say. Thanks.

Comment: I have a query here. After following the workflow you mentioned, suppose I realised that the commit I made on myBranch needs to be reworked. But now myBranch is way ahead of that commit after fetching from upstream and rebasing. So how to tackle it?

Comment: You simply add new commits which will fix your coffee in this branch. And then push as usual.

Comment: OK.I was actually trying to do something like 'git commit --amend'.

Comment: You can do that as well: since you are the only one working on that branch, you would do a push --force after your amend.